# Changing which column is resized when the window is resizing in WPF

Tags: wpf, grid, resize, responsive

i'm developping a WPF App using a grid to structure elements. 
If i resize the width of the window, only the last column is resized. I'd like to be able to change which column is resized when the window is resized, from code.

I hope my question is clear, ask any question if it isn't.

Thanks

Comment: Set a `*` [GridLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.gridlength) for the Width of the desired column, and a fixed or auto width for the others.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the `Column`'s `Width` property to multiple values to adjust that.

Here are the possible values:

- `*` - fill
- `Auto` - take as much space as needed for the content
- `50` - or any number means fixed width

Here's the fun stuff:

- When multiple `Column`s have the `Width` set to `*` they scale up or down equally.
- You can also set the width to of one column to `*` and another one's to `3*`. The one with the Width `3*` will be three times as wide, etc.